# How to prove that $\sigma_{k+1}(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n}d^k \cdot\phi(d)\cdot\sigma_{k}(\frac{n}{d})$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, dirichlet-convolution

How to prove  that $\sigma_{k+1}(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n}d^k \cdot\phi(d)\cdot\sigma_{k}(\frac{n}{d})$

I've tried using Dirichlet's convolution but the $d^k$ term seems to be something I can't resolve.

Comment: What is your definition of $\phi_k$?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Comment: Why not look at the corresponding Dirichlet series.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: The product  $d^k \phi(d)$ is multiplicative.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function

Comment: The resulting function is multiplicative, so one thing to do (although not the most elegant) is to prove it just at prime powers. Another option is to use some of the additional structure you have here; in particular, note that $d^k$ isn't  just multiplicative but is completely multiplicative. You may be able to use that (I haven't checked).

Comment: I'll try using that for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @reuns mentioned, it is possible to prove it using Dirichlet series. First, we have
$$
\zeta(s)\zeta(s-k) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\sigma_{k}(n)}{n^{s}} 
$$
This follows from direct computation:

$$
\zeta(s)\zeta(s-k) = \sum_{n, m\geq 1} \frac{1}{n^{s}m^{s-k}} = \sum_{n, m\geq 1} \frac{m^{k}}{(nm)^{s}}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{d|n} \frac{d^{k}}{n^{s}} = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\sigma_{k}(n)}{n^{s}}
$$
(of course, one need to consider convergence issues, but this can be resolved once we only consider $s$ with sufficiently large $\Re s$.) Also, we have
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{\phi(n)}{n^{s}} = \frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}
$$
which follows from $\sum_{d|n} \phi(d) =n$.

Then, using Dirichlet convolution, the equation just follows from 
$$
\zeta(s)\zeta(s-k-1) = \frac{\zeta(s-k-1)}{\zeta(s-k)}\cdot \zeta(s)\zeta(s-k)
$$